# Can User.Identity.GetUserId() be faked by a user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Can `User.Identity.GetUserId()` be faked by a user? Or is it safe to assume that it will always return an `UserId` for which an user exists or null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ASP.Net Identity, those details are claims that are encrypted by the web server, and stored in a cookie.

How secure is it?  That's something that's too broad and opinion based to get into here, but this may hold some relevance: [How secure is ASP.NET Identity session cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933969/how-secure-is-asp-net-identity-session-cookie)

Suffice to say that it would not be a trivial exercise for a user to send a fake user id.

Comment: I guess that i will have to check in the database if an user with the specified id really exist, to avoid fake cookies 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Found something helpful related to your question.
  [How to get current user, and how to use User class in MVC5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448637/how-to-get-current-user-and-how-to-use-user-class-in-mvc5)