# How to encrypt ASP.NET Identity authentication cookie using AES256

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encryption, cookies, asp.net-identity, aes

I have an MVC 5 project using Identity for handling authentication in the app.

From what I can tell, the cookie sent back to the client is encrypted with a minimum key length of 128 bits - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21955615/6427190).

I would like to use AES256 as the encryption mechanism. Is it possible to specify 256 bits when encrypting the cookie?

Thanks
TG

Comment: Which version of the Identity framework are you using? The [default hash](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/PasswordHasher.cs) is generated using *PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA256, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 10000 iterations* for version 3. If you need to replace that you will have to implement `IPasswordHasher` on your own.